# Rsync Excludes Folders

Tags: shell, scripting, rsync

I am running a rsync script and I want to exclude certain folders. I know with rsync you have to create a `.txt` file and add all the excludes in there but I am wondering is it possible to just have a global string in the script that includes all the excludes I want and then just added that global into the rsync command?

**Global String Example**

```
ROOT_EXCLUDE="--exclude=/dev --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/temp --exclude=/run --exlucde=/mnt --exlcude=/media
```

**Rsync Command**

```
rsync -au --exclude 'ROOT_EXCLUDE' /Users/Me/Home /Users/me/Backup
```

Comment: Try just `$ROOT_EXCLUDE` instead `--exclude 'ROOT_EXCLUDE'`

Comment: You are also missing the ending " for the ROOT_EXCLUDE

Comment: @Costas that didnt work, I just stuck to the normal way with a .txt file

Comment: @GMaster that was just an error in copying the code over

Comment: Try: export ROOT_EXCLUDE="--exclude=/dev --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/temp --exclude=/run --exlucde=/mnt --exlcude=/media"
And then: rsync -au $ROOT_EXCLUDE /Users/Me/Home /Users/me/Backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the elements of your exclude list don't contain any whitespace or any wildcards, you can define a `ROOT_EXCLUDE` variable and use it unquoted. Unquoted variable expansions split the value of the variable at each whitespace sequence¹; then each element is expanded as a wildcard pattern if it contains any wildcard.

```
ROOT_EXCLUDE="--exclude=/dev --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/temp --exclude=/run --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media"
rsync -au $ROOT_EXCLUDE /Users/Me/Home /Users/me/Backup
```

If you want to use wildcards in the exclusion list, that will work in standard shells provided that you have no file whose name matches the pattern. That's a slippery assumption for words like `--exclude=*.bak` and often not the case if you write `--exclude *.bak`. To avoid this pitfall, you can turn off wildcard expansion.

```
ROOT_EXCLUDE="--exclude=/dev --exclude=*.bak"
set -f
rsync -au $ROOT_EXCLUDE /Users/Me/Home /Users/me/Backup
set +f
```

In shells that support arrays (ksh, bash, zsh, but not plain sh), you can put the list of arguments in an [array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays). This is the recommended method to stuff a list of arguments into a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
…
ROOT_EXCLUDE=('--exclude=/dev' '--exclude=*.bak')
rsync -au "${ROOT_EXCLUDE[@]}" /Users/Me/Home /Users/me/Backup
```

Plain sh (any Bourne/POSIX shell, e.g. `sh` or `dash`) has a single unnamed array (the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, …) which you can set with `set -- …`. If you need to temporarily change the positional parameters, make the temporary change in a function: each function call has its own set of positional parameters.

```
set -- '--exclude=/dev' '--exclude=*.bak'
rsync -au "$@" /Users/Me/Home /Users/me/Backup
```

Rather than spell out a list of directories to exclude, you should pass the `-x` option, to skip mount points. This will take care of `/proc`, `/sys`, etc. You will then however need to explicitly include all sources if you want to back up files across multiple partitions. If you're backing up home directories, there probably aren't in-memory filesystems to skip anyway, but there might be network filesystems or other FUSE filesystems.

```
rsync -ax /Users/Me/Home /Users/me/Backup
```

¹  <sub>More generally, based on the value of `IFS`.</sub>